# how to get notifiaction for saved location on android googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, notifications, gps, reminders

i want notification on saved location,in android,google maps,
problem in my code is when i save the location far from my current place,and i want pop ups at that particulr saved location,but when i just move,it give me popups right on the current place...

This is the service class of my projct...:

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener{

    //private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    SharedPrefs sharedPrefs;


    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    //private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 600 ; // 10 min

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DataSource ds = new DataSource(MyLocationService.this);
        ds.open();
        ArrayList<MLocation> locs  = ds.getAllLocations();
        ds.close();
        if(locs!=null)
        {
            if(locs.size()>0)
            {
                ArrayList<Double>diffs = new ArrayList<Double>();

                for(int i=0;i<locs.size();i++)
                {
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(locs.get(i).getLatitude());
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(locs.get(i).getLongitude()); 
                    double dist = distance(latitude, longitude, location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 'K');
                    diffs.add(dist);
                    Log.i("GoogleMapsV2", i+" :"+dist);
                }
                //Collections.sort(diffs);
                int minIndex = diffs.indexOf(Collections.min(diffs));
                Toast.makeText(this, "You Are at "+locs.get(minIndex).getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.i("GoogleMapsV2" , " min:"+diffs.get(0));
                String category = locs.get(minIndex).getCategory();
                //changeRingerMode(category);

                SharedPrefs sp = new SharedPrefs(this);
                if(category.matches("Home"))
                {
                    if(sp.getNotificationBoolean())

                        showNotification1(this, sharedPrefs.getToDoListHome());

                    if(sp.getProfileBoolean())
                    changeRingerMode(sharedPrefs.getProfileHome());

                }
                else if(category.matches("Work"))
                {
                    if(sp.getProfileBoolean())
                    changeRingerMode(sharedPrefs.getProfileWork());


                    if(sp.getNotificationBoolean())
                    showNotification1(this, sharedPrefs.getToDoListWork());
                }
                else if(category.matches("Market"))
                {
                    if(sp.getProfileBoolean())
                    changeRingerMode(sharedPrefs.getProfileMarket());

                    if(sp.getNotificationBoolean())
                    showNotification1(this,sharedPrefs.getToDoListMarket());
                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Locs is Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    void changeRingerMode(String ringerMode)
    {
        AudioManager am;
        am= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(ringerMode.matches("Normal"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Normal Mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }
        else if(ringerMode.matches("Vibrate"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vibrate Mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        }
        else if(ringerMode.matches("Silent"))
                {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Silent Mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default:Normal Mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }

    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    void showNotification(Context context, String todoList)
    {



        // new DrawGraph().showNotification();
        // define sound URI, the sound to be played when there's a notification
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        // intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Categories.class);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent1 , 0);

        // this is it, we'll build the notification!
        // in the addAction method, if you don't want any icon, just set the first param to 0
        Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)

            .setContentTitle("To Do")
            .setContentText(todoList)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSound(soundUri)

            .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager=  (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);;

        // If you want to hide the notification after it was selected, do the code below
        // myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);
    }
    void showNotification1(Context context, String todoList)
    {


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

       /***
        * Creating Alert Dialogue To show Categories
        */
      //  alertDialog.addContentView(listView, new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       // alertDialog.add(input, new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        alertDialog.setTitle("To Do");
        alertDialog.setMessage(todoList);
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
        });
        AlertDialog alert =  alertDialog.create();

        alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);


        alert.show();
    }
    /**
     * distance Between Two latitudes and longitudes
     * @param lat1
     * @param lon1
     * @param lat2
     * @param lon2
     * @param unit
     * @return
     */
     private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
          double theta = lon1 - lon2;
          double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
          dist = Math.acos(dist);
          dist = rad2deg(dist);
          dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
          if (unit == 'K') {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
          } else if (unit == 'N') {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
            }
          return (dist);
        }

        /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
        /*::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :*/
        /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
        private double deg2rad(double deg) {
          return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
        }

        /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
        /*::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :*/
        /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
        private double rad2deg(double rad) {
          return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
        }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, provider+" Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, provider+" Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("GoogleMapsV2" ,"Service Started");
        sharedPrefs = new SharedPrefs(MyLocationService.this);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        getLocation();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Provider is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) 
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            0, //MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, 
                            this);

                    Log.d("Network", "Network");

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                //MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, 
                                0,this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
}
```

and these are SQLitehelper classes :

```
    public class DataSource {

  // Database fields
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
  private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DISCRIPTION, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATEGORY };

  public DataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
  }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }
  public void read() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
      }


  public MLocation createLocation(String latitude,String longitude,String discription, int category) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DISCRIPTION, discription);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION, null,
        values);
   Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION,
        allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
        null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    MLocation newMessage = cursorToLocation(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newMessage;
  }

  public void deleteLocation(MLocation loc) {
    long id = loc.getId();
    System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
    database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
  }
  /**
   * update a location
   * @param location
   */
  public void updateMessage(MLocation location) {


        String q = "UPDATE "+MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION+" SET "+
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DISCRIPTION+" = '"+location.getDescription()
                +"' WHERE "+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID+" = "+location.getId();
        database.execSQL(q);
        System.out.println("Rows Updated: " +q);
      }


  public ArrayList<MLocation> getAllLocations() {
    ArrayList<MLocation> locs = new ArrayList<MLocation>();
    try
    {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION,allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      MLocation loc = cursorToLocation(cursor);
      locs.add(loc);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return locs;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }


  private MLocation cursorToLocation(Cursor cursor) {
    MLocation loc = new MLocation();
    loc.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    loc.setDescription(cursor.getString(1));
   loc.setLatitude(cursor.getString(2));
   loc.setLongitude(cursor.getString(3));
   loc.setCategoryInt(cursor.getInt(4));
    return loc;
  }
}
```

AND

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String TABLE_LOCATION = "location";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
  public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitute";
  public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
  public static final String COLUMN_DISCRIPTION = "discription";
  public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "profile.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+TABLE_LOCATION+
            "( " +COLUMN_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ COLUMN_LATITUDE+ " text not null,"+COLUMN_LONGITUDE+" text not null, "+COLUMN_DISCRIPTION +" text, "
                        +COLUMN_CATEGORY+" integer); ";


  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }


  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATION);
    onCreate(db);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: actualy i want gps reminder,location based reminder,when i save location by placing marker ,i want popup or notification for that place only....